# Ionic Framework : Text of the application is blurry when testing app on Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I just had a huge deception! I've just finished the first version of my app and so I went on and I tested it on my Android device... The content of the app is blurry!

You can see it on the screenshots. It looks like the text does not display correctly in the list. You can also see that the save button is a little bit deformed.

Where does it come from?

Well, I have remarked that elements of the app that I have customized using a style.css appear blurry and that the ones belonging to the Ionic framework appear correctly. The problem may come from here as it may come from something completely different, I honestly don't know.

How can I fix this?

Pretty please!

Thank you!

PS: The screenshots are actually a little less blurry than how it looks in the app.

EDIT:

```
#test{
color: white;
margin-top: 5px;
}
#location{
float: left;
}
#timeIn{
text-align: right;
color: red;
}
#timeOut{
text-align: right;
color: green;
}
#check{
display: block;
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenchot 2]

Comment: can you post  your css ? I have never faced that issue developping on Ionic android / ios

Comment: On the Android emulator everything works perfectly. It is only on device that the problem is present.

Comment: What is your device ? Version of Android ? Your css is very simple and shall not impact the layout

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S2: GT-I9100 ; Android: 4.2.2

Comment: Have you tried a sample app on your phone? Is everything working well?

Comment: Yes, I did. No problem with a sample app.

Comment: Some older phone have problems with scaling in a font. Maybe you have better results with setting -webkit-font-smoothing to antialiased or auto in your css?

Comment: In my opinion is definitely a problem of scaling. I have juste noticed that in Landscape there are no problem of display. The problem is there only in portrait. The problem occurs also with buttons, so what can I do for these?I will run a test with your proposition. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue, it only occurred during development while using a remote host. Test it by not using `--livereload` flag to confirm.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with **font rendering**.
Has *nothing* to do with `--livereload`

You can bypass this either using font-smoothing in CSS, force it through  the browser/webview or through other means.

My suggestion is to enable anti-aliasing CSS:

```
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

..on another note, it seems ionic automatically switches to "ios" mode if subpixel/anti-aliasing is enabled. Go figure :)